# strptime giving "implicit declaration" and "undefined reference"

Tags: c, strptime, time.h

So, when I use the function `strptime` I get both a warning:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'strptime'
```

and an error after that:

```
undefined reference to 'strptime'
```

Yes, I've included `time.h`. Here is a small sample code of me using it.

```
#include <time.h>

void my_function()
{
    char buf* = "2016-02-05 12:45:10";
    struct tm time*;
    ...
    strptime(buf, "%F %T", &time);
    ...
}
```

I know `time.h` is working because in the same `.c` file, I'm using `strftime`, `time_t`, and `'struct tm` from `time.h` without a problem. I know it's `strptime`, because when I comment that line of code, it compiles without any problems.

Comment: the statement: `#include <time.h>` needs to be preceded by: `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` so the function prototype is visible. or, for gcc, use parameter `-std=gnu99` or `-std=gnu11`

Comment: or build with `-D_GNU_SOURCE`, which is less restrictive than `_XOPEN_SOURCE`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to tell us on what platform you are, your compiler version, arguments ...

In any case, `strptime` is not in standard C, but comes with POSIX. Probably you got your compiler options wrong such that it doesn't provide you with POSIX extensions to C. With gcc this would be to use `-std=gnu11` instead of `-std=c11`, for example.